# How to add browserstack capabilities using webdriverIO + Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io, browserstack

Trying to setup WebdriverIO + Typescript + Browserstack, but when I try to add the capabilities as it's shown below, it says that these types are not assignable to type 'WebdriverIO', don't know what to do.

[image]

This is my tsconfig.ts file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "node-fetch",
      "jest",
      "webdriverio/async",
      "wdio-wiremock-service"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
capabilities: [{
    'bstack:options' : {
        "osVersion" : "10.0",
        "deviceName" : "Samsung Galaxy S20",
        "realMobile" : "true",
        "local" : "false",
        "userName" : "USERNAME",
        "accessKey" : "ACCESS_KEY",
    },
    "browserName" : "Android"
}]
```

Browserstack site has a Capabilities generator (choose NodeJS on the right) https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities?tag=selenium-4

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the sample tests and config from https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-examples-webdriverio/tree/main/resources/conf and use the config to set up your tests.